# Problems with webserver plc advance tia portal siemens

Tags: webserver, plc, siemens, tia-portal

I'm trying to make an example web server with the s7 plc advance v2, but I can't get the page to load properly.

The steps I do are the following:

- Configuring the Siemens PLCSIM Virtual Ethernet Adapter
  [image]
- Configure advance plc
  [image]
- Configurations in tia portal v15

[image]
[image]

- Compile configuration/load configuration to virtual plc
  [image]
- Try in browser. I get the following error:
  [image]

Someone help me please, I've already reinstalled several times, I've tried version 16 of tia portal and plc advance 15 and 16, but it always gives me the same problem. i have windows 10 pro

Comment: Have you tried changing the web server's Everyone access level to Administrative (all options ticked)?  Have you tried deleting and re-creating the PLCSim Advanced instance?

Comment: @CliffPennalligen I tell you that I managed to solve the problem, for a strange reason the browsers reject the connection to the advance plc in its version 2 and 3, I tried several browsers and the one that worked for me was with firefox with version 3 of the advance plc, then install version 4 of plc advance and that one works with current browsers.

Answer (score 1):

your html code isn't compatible with plc. search for webserver examples from siemens and you will fix it. Google this phrase " 68011496 siemens industry " and you see how to modify your code to be shown properly.